# How to implement smooth map width transition of Mapbox GL map?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have CSS3 transition for reducing width of map element. I have to trigger map.resize() when changing map block width to update map width programmatically. It jumps to new width, without transition (what is expected)

Is there any way to implement animation of map block width transition?
Except changing map block width by JS and triggering resize on each frame.

Another way is to create block where map will be rendered covering full width, and then shrink that block with overflow:hidden and use offset to translate map center point a bit. But in that case we get wide map, and tiles will be loaded in the background (even that part of block is hidden) i suppose.